# Multilingual site PHP switching method

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out, what I am missing to make two lingual website for PHP pages.

In the root folder, I have `index.php` and other PHP files along with the `include` folder, which contains `lang-switch.php`, `navbar.php` with other PHP files, `footer.php`, `header.php`, etc. `navbar.php` contains:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="?lang=en">En</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="?lang=es">Es</a>                  
  </li>
```

and `lang-switch.php`:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en" ;
}else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])){
    if($_GET['lang']){
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    } else if ($_GET['lang'] == "es") {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "es";
    }
    require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";
}
```

in the root folder, I also have the `languages` folder with two files `en.php`:

```
$lang = array(
   "home" => "Home",
   "aboutus" => "About Us",
   "contactinfo" => "Contact Information",
   "nodatafound" => "No Data Found",
);
```

and `es.php`:

```
$lang = array(
   "home" => "Principal",
   "aboutus" => "Sobre",
   "contactinfo" => "Información del contacto",
   "nodatafound" => "Datos no encontrados",
);
```

then in `footer.php`, which is in the same `includes` folder, I include:

```
 include('lang-switch.php');
```

to pass in `html` tag:

```
 <div><a href="index.php" class="text-dark"><?php $lang['home'] ?> </a></div>
 <div><a href="about_us.php" class="text-dark"><?php $lang['aboutus'] ?></a></div>
```

I got:

> Notice: Undefined variable: lang in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\site\includes\footer.php on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: lang in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\site\includes\footer.php on line 17

with using `<?php echo $lang['home'] ?>`:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'aboutus' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\site\includes\footer.php on line 25
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'home' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\user\site\includes\footer.php on line 26

Comment: `<?php $lang['home'] ?>` doen't seem to be doing anything. Should it be `<?php echo $lang['home'] ?>`?

Comment: @user3425506 Hello, same result

Comment: How about `<?php $lang['aboutus'] ?>`?

Comment: @user3425506  It is an Undefined variable and with using an echo Illegal string offset. Please check, I've edited the question

Comment: When `$_SESSION['lang']` is not `set`, then `require_once "languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";` is not called. Meaning `$lang` is not defined. Is that right ?

Comment: @Clément Baconnier Hello, Undefined index with  $lang = array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would probably work for you. I tried to add comments to make it as clear as possible.

Also, this assumes you are using PHP 7.4+ and that you are running `session_start()` somewhere before this code starts.

I did not test this at all, but is should at least give you a start.

**navbar.php**

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="?lang=en">En</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="?lang=es">Es</a>                  
</li>
```

**functions.php** or **helpers.php** or whatever you want

```
<?php
/**
 * Get the current session language
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getLanguage()
{
    // default to 'en' if no language is set yet
    return $_SESSION['lang'] ?? 'en';
}

/**
 * Set the language based on the `lang` url param
 *
 * @return void
 */
function setLanguage()
{
    $known_languages = [
        'en',
        'es'
    ];

    // make sure $_GET['lang'] is not empty
    // and make sure the new language is known to us
    if ( !empty($_GET['lang']) &&
        $_SESSION['lang'] !== $_GET['lang'] &&
        in_array( $_GET['lang'], $known_languages )
    ) {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    }
}

/**
 * Get the $lang variable with all the translated strings
 * This should probably be a JSON file or something similar
 *
 * @return array
 */
function getTranslations() {
    include "languages/" . getLanguage() . ".php";
    /* @var array $lang*/

    return $lang;
}

/**
 * Get the translated string from our list of translations
 * Print a translation missing message if not found
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return string
 */
function getTranslatedString( $string ) {
    $string_values = getTranslations();

    return $string_values[$string] ?? "Not Translated ( $string )";
}
/**
 * Prints the translated string from our list of translations
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @return void
 */
function printTranslatedString( $string ) {
    echo getTranslatedString( $string );
}
```

The translation files stay as you have them, even though you may probably make use of JSON or something similar.

Then, you should run the `setLanguage()` function somewhere before the output of your HTML starts otherwise you will end up with warnings like:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at ...

And then, in your HTML you should be able to use it like:

```
<div>
    <a href="index.php" class="text-dark">
        <?php printTranslatedString('home') ?> 
    </a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="about_us.php" class="text-dark">
        <?php printTranslatedString('aboutus') ?>
    </a>
</div>
```